# Joining javascript in HTML with to not specific link

Tags: javascript, php, html

## Background Information

I have a website and a library hosted on it using a subdomain

`domain.com` is the website.
`cdn.domain.com` is the library.

At `domain.com`, I have the file `index.html` with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div> TEST </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.domain.com/test.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

---

## Problem

I am able to load the JavaScript file from `cdn.domain.com/test.js`, but I want to be able to load it from just `cdn.domain.com`, so that the `<script>` tag looks like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.domain.com"></script>
```

Should I upload `index.html` to `cdn.domain.com` with the code from `test.js`?

Comment: Sorry but I dont get! if you want to load a file you need to secify your file name like you do in question `<script src="https://cdn.domain.com/test.js"></script>` you cant load a file without calling it. *But* I will be glad to see you find a solution and share with us.

Comment: I've seen it on some site where javascript is loaded only from a link to a domain

Comment: You need to upload the file to the server your cdn domain points to. Your code does not specify a file, just a root domain address. ` <script src="https://cdn.domain.com"></script> `

Answer (score 0):

## `.htaccess` Solution

In the `.htaccess` file in the root of the domain `https://cdn.domain.com` on your web server, you can add the following line:

```
Redirect /index.html /test.js
```

This will redirect any traffic from `https://cdn.domain.com` to `https://cdn.domain.com/test.js`. As a result, when the browser requests the file at `https://cdn.domain.com`, the web server returns the file at `https://cdn.domain.com/test.js`.

Answer (score 0):

## Node.js Solution

If your web server has Node.js support, you can create the following Node.js program and run it on the web server at the domain `https://cdn.domain.com`:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 80;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    if (req.url == "/") {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
        fs.readFile('./test.js', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.end(err.message);
            } else {
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.end(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        fs.readFile('./' + req.url, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.end(err.message);
            } else {
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.end(data);
            }
        });
    }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {});
```

This will redirect any traffic from `https://cdn.domain.com` to `https://cdn.domain.com/test.js`. As a result, when the browser requests the file at `https://cdn.domain.com`, the web server returns the file at `https://cdn.domain.com/test.js`. If any other file is requested, the server returns the requested file instead of the `test.js` file.